# Show/hide home button depending on route

Tags: ember.js

I'm doing the first steps in Ember.js and I am quite confused by the different approaches and solutions provided in communities.

I have a quite small application that has a application template and content templates which I navigate through by link-to.

My application template has a home button which I want to hide and show depending on the route i am navigating to. How do I do that?

I am using plain-old JavaScript. No preprocessors or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use global `currentRouteName` property directly in your controller

in your application controller

```
hideHomeButtonRoutes: ['index', 'login'],
isHomeButtonVisible: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function(){
  return this.get('hideHomeButtonRoutes').indexOf(this.get('currentRouteName')) > -1;
})
```

in your `template`

```
{{#if isHomeButtonVisible}} <button>home</button> {{/if}}
```

here is working [example](https://ember-twiddle.com/c98527cf6c5d0e11a4cc?openFiles=othe-route.route.js%2Capplication.template.hbs&route=%2Fother-route)

Comment: Could you specify route and controller in for your solution? Do I need to set setupController for every route of my application? Or is it somesort of application route? Is controller kind of a application controller?

Comment: this is only done once same level as your home button, if it is in application template put everything in application route, controller

Comment: Like this?

 <code>
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 hideHomeButtonRoutes: ['index', 'intro'],
 isHomeButtonVisible: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function() {
  return this.get('hideHomeButtonRoutes').indexOf(this.get('currentRouteName')) > 1;
 })
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 setupController: function (controller, model) {
  controller.set('currentRouteName', this.router.currentRouteName);
 },
});
</code>

Somehow doesn't work. I don't get it.

Comment: sorry I missed something I am updating answer

Comment: doesn't work either :/ I am using Ember.js 2.2. Is this important? Here my code:
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
 hideHomeButtonRoutes: ['index', 'intro'],
 isHomeButtonVisible: Ember.computed('currentRouteName', function() {
  return this.get('hideHomeButtonRoutes').indexOf(this.get('currentRouteName')) > 1;
 })
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 actions: {
     loading: function() {
        if (this.controller) {
         this.controller.set('currentRouteName', this.router.currentRouteName);
        } 
      }
    }
});

Comment: I think the operator should be `=== -1` instead of  `> -1`.